# Where does PHP's syslog write error messages in windows?

Tags: php, syslog

I'm currently running a drupal site on windows using WAMP.  From reading the API docs, I think that drupal uses PHP's syslog function to log status messages.  I was wondering if there was a way to configure the event viewer to show the log messages generated by PHP's syslog function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably event viewer?

Answer (score 2):

1) Let PHP execute `syslog()`. Example:

`syslog(LOG_INFO, 'This is my test message');`

2) In this example I will looking for: `This is my test message`.

Open run: <kbd>Windows button</kbd>  + <kbd>R</kbd>

Type: `eventvwr`

Then consult this screenshot (it's in dutch language)

[image]

Let's zoom in:

[image]

We found it!